# xcode wrong error. I deleted the line with the error and the error is still there, on a blank line

Tags: xcode7

I just delete the var `isTied` and an error appears at the next line where I referenced this var. So I delete the reference but the error is still there, even with the blank line.

I tried to put back the variable and a reference to it, but no effect.

Another error appears at class ViewController: UIViewController : "Class "ViewController" has no initializers". And refers to an variable that I leave without value

```
var whoIsTheWinner : Int
```

So I just add a value:

```
var whoIsTheWinner : Int = 3
```

The error remains at the class ViewController and at the variable the error is now gray instead of red...

I can't see any errors and I already tried to close and re-open xcode.

Any ideas?

My Xcode is 7.2(7C68)

[image: xcode strange error]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a deep clean of the project?

Clean build with

```
Shift+Cmd+K
```

Clean build folder with

```
Option+Shift+Command+K
```